# Trying to get a range from a list but it is not right

Tags: python

idk what i am doing wrong

```
#This is just a greeting
print("Hello Welcome to ACME GRocery Store ")
#input to get the weight of packages
#Example 10, 20, 38, 49, 18, 29, 10, 39
weight= input("Please enter the weight's of all packages with commas in between: ").split(",")
weight.sort()
small = range(0, 5) from weight
medium = range(6, 10) from weight
large = range (11, 25) from weight
extra_large = range(26, 9999999999) from weight
print ("Amount of packages submitted = ", len(weight))
print ("Amount of small packages submitted = ", len(small))
print ("Amount of medium packages submitted = ", len(medium))
print ("Amount of large packages submitted = ", len(large))
print ("Amount of extra large packages submitted = ", len(extra_large))`
```

i am trying to get the diffrent weight and how many times they were mentioned so lets say 2 small

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: You seem to be inventing your own syntax, then being surprised when it doesn't word.  For example, `range(0, 5) from weight` isn't Python.  The `from` keyword is used by import statements, e.g. `from math import sqrt`.  It's not going to magically do something else you have in mind just because you'd like it to.  Try to learn the language as it is, not as you wish it were.

Comment: You could try replacing `small = range(0, 5) from weight` with `small = sum([0<=w<=5 for w in weights])`